# Como dar valor a un char *a el cual sume todos los argumentos introducidos por el terminal guardados en char *argv[i]

Tags: c

soy un novato que ha empezado a aprender a programar en C en Linux.

Al hacer un ejercicio propuesto, me he atascado al descubrir que un char *a no puede guardar todos los valores que hay en otro array[i], específicamente en un char *argv[i], querria preguntar si hay alguna manera de guardar los valores de *argv[i] en un solo char *a.
Por ejemplo si introduzco por el terminal:

```
$~ ./Prueba.out ps alx.
```

"ps" estaría guardado en argv[1] y "alx" estaría guardado en argv[2], quiero un char* que sea la suma de los valores de argv[1] y argv[2] tal que ,

```
char *a = argv[1] + argv[2] + argv[i]...
```

Ps: Lo necesito contenido en un char porque despues se lo tengo que pasar a otra funcion que crea un proceso hijo el cual imprime lo que le he pasado como una orden shell, de la forma sh -c a.

Perdón si fuese muy obvio.

Edicion:
Primero ante todo, les agradezco por la ayuda proporcionada y por la inexactitud de mi problema (sumar en vez de concatenar), el cual causo que no pudiese encontrar la respuesta por google...
Ambas respuestas me han ayudado y me han recordado el importante hecho de hacerme cargo de la memoria en C.
Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manera que mejor se me ocurre es con memoria dinámica, puesto que con [strcat](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) podrías llegar a tener problemas de memoria.

C tiene un amplio acceso a espacios de memoria, por lo cual se debe tener cuidado al trabajar con memoria, puesto que podrías sobrescribir espacios de memoria a los cuales no tienes acceso.

La solución con strcat sería ir concatenando todos los arreglos que se introducen por consola. Sin embargo, esta solución requeriría que de antemano supieras cuántos caracteres como máximo se introducirán por consola. De lo contrario, strcat podría escribir sobre espacios de memoria los cuales no deberías de manipular.

Atendiendo a los comentarios sobre la anterior respuesta; te dejo una solución que aunque no permite un número "ilimitado" de caracteres podría ayudarte a lograr lo que quieres sin perjudicar la memoria.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512

/**
 *
 * @param argc Number of arguments passed on command execution
 * @param argv Array of string arguments
 * @return program exit status
 */
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    size_t readed = 0;

    char concatenated[BUFFER_SIZE];
    concatenated[0] = '\000';
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        readed += strlen(argv[i]);
        if (readed > BUFFER_SIZE){
            perror("Console arguments are too long");
            break;
        }
        strncat(concatenated, argv[i], BUFFER_SIZE - readed);
    }

    printf("%s", concatenated);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

- El macro `BUFFER_SIZE 512` le indica al programa el número máximo de caracteres que esperas recibir.
- `size_t readed = 0;` equivalente a `unsigned long long readed = 0;` te permite conocer cuántos caracteres tienes en el arreglo
- `strlen(argv[i])` te devuelve la longitud de caracteres que contiene el puntero `argv*[i]`
- `readed > BUFFER_SIZE` esta comparación te permite saber que aún tienes espacio suficiente para almacenar en tu arreglo
- [`strncat`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat) te permite concatenar dos arreglos con máximo de "n" caracteres (tercer argumento `BUFFER_SIZE - readed`)

Además te invito a probar cuando tengas más experiencia a hacer el mismo programa pero con memoria dinámica y probar con wchar, que permite un rango más amplio de caracteres que char.

Comment: Bueno, de cualquier manera agradezco tu comentario y trataré de ser más explicativo en mis respuestas :)

Comment: Siendo que has reescrito completamente tu respuesta con una solución mas sencilla y mas segura, te llevas el +1 de mi parte. Borrare los comentarios ya que ya no aplican a la respuesta que tienes ahora.

Comment: Gracias de igual forma por tus comentarios :)

Answer (score 0):

Con la suma de los valores supongo que te refieres a concatenar los `char[]`. Lo que puedes hacer es usar la funcion `strcat` para juntarlos. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Lo inicializamos en 0
    char result[MAX_STR_SIZE] = {0};

    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        // Concatenamos al final de result el argv
        strcat(result, argv[i]);
    }

    // Lo imprimimos
    printf("%s", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Entonces al correlo queda:

```
$~ ./a.out ps alx
psalx
```

Ya de lo que tienes aqui espero que ya solo necesites hacer modificaciones sencillas para hacer tu programa. Mucha suerte

Comment: No uses esta solución por favor. Te explico... En C se puede manipular la memoria de la computadora de manera muy específica y no se tiene como en otros lenguajes "algo" que te impida modificar la memoria para mal.

Imagina que tienes tu límite en 512 caracteres, sin embargo, al momento de ejecutar tu programa le paso una cantidad de argumentos de consola de 1000 carecteres. Esto haría que los 488 caracteres restantes se almacenaran en memoria que NO HAZ RESERVADO Y LA CUAL PODRÍA ESTAR SIENDO ODUPADA. Al modificar esos bytes, el dispositivo puede tener un gran error

Comment: El dispositivo no va a tener un grave error, el sitema operativo va a evitar que toques esa memoria si llegas a pasarte por mucho. Y si esperas mas de 512 caracteres, solo haz mas grande el array

Comment: Imagina un segundo caso. introdujiste los 1000 caracteres y la memoria que no reservaste pero ocupaste no está ocupada. Ahora en el siguiente paso de tu programa solicitas más memoria, y como tú reservaste sólo 512 caracteres, la computadora le asigna el espacio de memoria a tu nueva variable y sobre escribe tu entrada de la línea de comandos

Comment: No es que tenga un grave error, pero puede llegar a ocurrir un error, además es muy mala práctica que por pensar que no pasa nada malo no lo hagas de la manera correcta

Comment: *"además es muy mala práctica que por pensar que no pasa nada malo no lo hagas de la manera correcta"*. No se si a ti cuando te estaban enseñando C te pedian que cada entrada del usuario la tuvieras que revisar? O solo usabas `scanf`? A la mayoria nos enseñaron con `scanf`, aunque sea una forma pesima de leer la entrada del usuario. Porque? Porque el revisar la entrada del usuario es algo que haces ya cuando son programas serios, pero cuando estas aprendiendo no tiene ningun punto. Primero sientas bien las bases, y luego vas añadiendo cosas para hacer robustos y seguros los programas.